# Deploying MVC & WCF on Windows Azure Websites

Tags: windows, azure, tfs, tfsbuild

I have a solution consist of 2 projects:
- MVC
- WCF

I'm using the visual studio online "I used a TFS on separated VM too but same problem".

Issue: I successfully deployed only the MVC but the wcf not working!!

Request: I hope to find an answer for how to deploy this solution on windows azure website with remotely Database!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that the continuous delivery to azure template will only deploy a single application. You would need to create a custom ContiniousDeliveryToAzure.xaml to deploy more than one site in a single build.

Or you can put each project into its own build.

If you have a shared component then you should publish it with Nuget and consume it with both other projects.

Comment: Yeah thats the main issue, that the continuous delivery doesn't support multiple applications. If ypu know any tutorial for how to customize this for my needs that will be very helpful, thanx anyway :)